# Programatically add Form Title to all Contact Form 7 forms?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact Form 7 in WordPress and I have many forms.

I'd like to add the form title (the `post_title` field in database terms) to all my existing forms, as a hidden field.

I'd like to use a hook so that I don't need to use a shortcode in each form in the admin area.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You may try this WP plugin: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

Comment: @gtamborero Thanks, but I don't want to add a new field to each form manually.

Comment: It's not the idea to add manually each field. post_title value will be dinamic

Answer (score 0):

you could use CF7's 'wpcf7_form_hidden_fields' filter before your form is displayed,

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_hidden_fields', 'add_form_title');
function add_job_title($hidden){
 $form = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form();
 $post = get_post($form->id());
 $hidden['cf7_title'] = $post->post_title; //form title slug.
 return $hidden;
}
```

when the form is submitted, `$_POST['cf7_title']` will have the value of the hidden field.